# k8s master node stuck in NotReady

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup a single node k8s cluster, but I am having issues with it being stuck in `NotReady`

I get this if I run `describe` on the node

```
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Fri, 13 May 2022 16:48:19 +0200   Fri, 13 May 2022 16:48:19 +0200   FlannelIsUp                  Flannel is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Fri, 13 May 2022 18:05:31 +0200   Fri, 13 May 2022 16:38:24 +0200   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Fri, 13 May 2022 18:05:31 +0200   Fri, 13 May 2022 16:38:24 +0200   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Fri, 13 May 2022 18:05:31 +0200   Fri, 13 May 2022 16:38:24 +0200   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                False   Fri, 13 May 2022 18:05:31 +0200   Fri, 13 May 2022 16:38:24 +0200   KubeletNotReady              container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.50.186
  Hostname:    intel-nuc
...
PodCIDR:                      10.244.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (6 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                 CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                 ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 etcd-intel-nuc                       100m (1%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (0%)       0 (0%)         87m
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-intel-nuc             250m (3%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         87m
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-intel-nuc    200m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         87m
  kube-system                 kube-flannel-ds-f4mz7                100m (1%)     100m (1%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      78m
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-gjbjn                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         87m
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-intel-nuc             100m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         88m
```

I can't find any errors on the node, and I've installed a flannel network controller and changed it's cidr setting to `10.244.0.0/24`, but other than that it is exactly what is on master in their git repo.

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-flannel-ds-f4mz7
I0513 14:48:18.130988       1 main.go:205] CLI flags config: {etcdEndpoints:http://127.0.0.1:4001,http://127.0.0.1:2379 etcdPrefix:/coreos.com/network etcdKeyfile: etcdCertfile: etcdCAFile: etcdUsername: etcdPassword: version:false kubeSubnetMgr:true kubeApiUrl: kubeAnnotationPrefix:flannel.alpha.coreos.com kubeConfigFile: iface:[] ifaceRegex:[] ipMasq:true subnetFile:/run/flannel/subnet.env publicIP: publicIPv6: subnetLeaseRenewMargin:60 healthzIP:0.0.0.0 healthzPort:0 iptablesResyncSeconds:5 iptablesForwardRules:true netConfPath:/etc/kube-flannel/net-conf.json setNodeNetworkUnavailable:true}
W0513 14:48:18.131094       1 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0513 14:48:18.427877       1 kube.go:120] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync
I0513 14:48:18.428024       1 kube.go:378] Starting kube subnet manager
I0513 14:48:19.428219       1 kube.go:127] Node controller sync successful
I0513 14:48:19.428249       1 main.go:225] Created subnet manager: Kubernetes Subnet Manager - intel-nuc
I0513 14:48:19.428258       1 main.go:228] Installing signal handlers
I0513 14:48:19.428558       1 main.go:454] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I0513 14:48:19.428616       1 match.go:189] Determining IP address of default interface
I0513 14:48:19.429528       1 match.go:242] Using interface with name wlp0s20f3 and address 192.168.50.186
I0513 14:48:19.429580       1 match.go:264] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.50.186)
I0513 14:48:19.429699       1 vxlan.go:138] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false Learning=false DirectRouting=false
I0513 14:48:19.430968       1 device.go:82] VXLAN device already exists
I0513 14:48:19.431213       1 device.go:90] Returning existing device
I0513 14:48:19.431823       1 kube.go:339] Setting NodeNetworkUnavailable
I0513 14:48:19.629092       1 main.go:332] Setting up masking rules
I0513 14:48:19.929866       1 main.go:353] Changing default FORWARD chain policy to ACCEPT
I0513 14:48:19.929994       1 main.go:366] Wrote subnet file to /run/flannel/subnet.env
I0513 14:48:19.930018       1 main.go:370] Running backend.
I0513 14:48:19.930040       1 main.go:391] Waiting for all goroutines to exit
I0513 14:48:19.930071       1 vxlan_network.go:61] watching for new subnet leases
I0513 14:48:19.932511       1 iptables.go:231] Some iptables rules are missing; deleting and recreating rules
I0513 14:48:19.932528       1 iptables.go:255] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/24 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j RETURN
I0513 14:48:20.027801       1 iptables.go:255] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/24 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0513 14:48:20.028018       1 iptables.go:231] Some iptables rules are missing; deleting and recreating rules
I0513 14:48:20.028037       1 iptables.go:255] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld forward -j ACCEPT
I0513 14:48:20.030548       1 iptables.go:255] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/24 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j RETURN
I0513 14:48:20.127958       1 iptables.go:255] Deleting iptables rule: -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld forward -j ACCEPT
I0513 14:48:20.128885       1 iptables.go:255] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/24 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0513 14:48:20.131400       1 iptables.go:243] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld forward -j ACCEPT
I0513 14:48:20.228048       1 iptables.go:243] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/24 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j RETURN
I0513 14:48:20.233896       1 iptables.go:243] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/24 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0513 14:48:20.333838       1 iptables.go:243] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/24 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j RETURN
I0513 14:48:20.432009       1 iptables.go:243] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/24 -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld masq -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0513 14:48:20.530266       1 iptables.go:243] Adding iptables rule: -d 10.244.0.0/24 -m comment --comment flanneld forward -j ACCEPT
```

I might not really know what I am reading in the logs for flannel, but from what I understand there are no real issues.
And the cni file seems to be correct

```
[munhunger@intel-nuc net.d]$ ls
10-flannel.conflist
[munhunger@intel-nuc net.d]$ cat 10-flannel.conflist 
{
  "name": "cbr0",
  "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "type": "flannel",
      "delegate": {
        "hairpinMode": true,
        "isDefaultGateway": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "portmap",
      "capabilities": {
        "portMappings": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
[munhunger@intel-nuc net.d]$ pwd
/etc/cni/net.d
```

am I missing something obvious, or why isn't my k8s node getting ready?

Comment: 1) Please check if you have flannel in the following directory.:/opt/cni/bin?
2) what is the output of $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS? is the kubelet started using the flannel config? You can check the kubelet startup arguments.

Comment: also getting this